# Sweet Alert Delete Confirmation in Laravel leading to an undefined URL

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, sweetalert

I have the following button to delete a record in my `Laravel` application.

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE','route' => ['inqueries.destroy', $inquery->id],'style'=>'display:inline']) !!}

{!! Form::button('<img class="nc-icon" src="../admin_icons/trash.svg" >', ['class' => 'btn btn-default btn_icon button delete-confirm','type'=>'submit']) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And as for the delete confirmation, I'm trying to use `sweet alerts`.

So I'm using the following `JS` code,

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('.delete-confirm').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const url = $(this).attr('href');
    swal({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: 'This record and it`s details will be permanantly deleted!',
        icon: 'warning',
        buttons: ["Cancel", "Yes!"],
    }).then(function(value) {
        if (value) {
            window.location.href = url;
        }
    });
});       
</script>
```

Even though once I hit delete it shows me the `sweet alert`, once I click on the yes button it redirects me to a `404` route.

```
http://testlink.local/admins/undefined
```

And the record doesn't get deleted too.

How can I set the delete route properly in my `JS` according to the button action route?

I've set my route as,

```
Route::resource('/admins/inqueries','Admin\InqueryController');
```

Answer (score 1):

The js code will be triggered for button. And the button does not have any `href` attribute that is why you are getting undefined in the result.

You can either use the parent method for the button to get the `href` attribute for the form element or directly use the form element to get the `href` attribute.

```
const url = $(this).parent().attr('href')
```

or

```
const url = $('form').attr('href')
```